# How to get the listView position value and pass it to another class through intent

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-intent, firebase-realtime-database

I have a listview which fetches data from the firebase database. when a user clicks on an item, he'll be taken to the next screen. how do I fetch the name of the item on which he clicked... Suppose he clicks on item "A" and is directed to the next class. In there I want that A to be displayed. I could use the putExtra method from intent but the data isn't in the code, it's in the database. Can someone help me with the code

This is the code for fetching data which is fine

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
String name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
//                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                al.add(name);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

I need to display that name in the next class in a `textview`

```
   name.setText();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This in your actvity

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Intent intent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourClassName.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",al.get(position));
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Now in receiving activity:

```
name.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can create a custom class adapter where you will extends an arrayadapter. After you redefine your getView method and just put some information in intent to send it to the other activity.